# A person who shares or likes or retweets everything they come across?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have come across a few folks who share, like or retweet everything they see. Is there a word to indicate their behavior/attitude/nature?

Comment: Am looking for a word to describe folks who simply post/share/tweet others content, nothing original. Ofcourse, they ain't plagiarizing - simply share/retweet/like everyting that they come across.

Comment: Sounds like a [*Twit*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twit).

Comment: @bib I'm partial to Twidiot/Twitiot

Comment: @DanNeely don't be a **Tweetist**!

Answer (score 7):

From Urban Dictionary:

Tweet monkey

He would have Tweet Diarrhea - Tweetspew has also been coined although there is an account featuring people spewing with that name too

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But then, can this word be used for folks who simply share content, nothing original?

Comment: Am looking for a word to describe folks who simply post/share/tweet others content, nothing original. Ofcourse, they ain't plagiarizing - simply share/retweet/like everything that they come across.

Comment: I would think so. Monkey denotes no intelligence used in the process

Answer (score 2):

For someone who's twitter account is largely unoriginal content I'd describe them as a [Retwit](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=retwit).

Answer (score 2):

My suggestions would be:

> serial retweeter/resharer

as someone who retweets or reshares repeatedly, or

> social media butterfly

a play on "social butterfly" which is sometimes used to describe someone who flits from table to table at parties socialising with different groups

Answer (score 1):

If they are chiefly doing this on Twitter you could call them *[chirpy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chirpy)*:-

> 1. Characterized by chirping tones: a bird with a chirpy song.
> 2. Tending to chirp: a chirpy parakeet.
> 3. Cheerful and good-humored: a chirpy radio announcer.

Answer (score 1):

The phenomena generally is known as an ***echo chamber***; and people who repeat content mindlessly are ***gossips***.

A hairdresser, for example, using their mouth vs. their iPhone to repeat information without consideration or insight would be a *gossip* regardless of the communication medium.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just be original and make my own label. How about a ***link-gooder***? (A pun on do-gooders.)

Answer (score 0):

In similar contexts people have been accused of being “human gateways”, however it is possible that this English expression is confined to a group of German Internet (or even Usenet) users.